# Removing text after a closing tag (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove text after a closing `</i>` tag when the user doesn't hover over the button any more.

I've tried the commented parts in the code maybe they can give you an idea of where I'm going wrong.

```js
$('#deleteButton').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  //$(this).find('i').html(' Delete Nest');
  $(this).find('i').after(' Delete Nest');
  //$(this).find('i').after(' <div>Delete Nest</div>');
}).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  //$(this).find('i').html('');

  console.log($(this).find('i').after());

  //$(this).find('i').after('');
  //$(this).find('i').childNodes[1].textContent;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the HTML of the button:

<button id="deleteButton" type="submit" name="_method" value="DELETE" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger muted muted-hover"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Instead of adding nothing it should remove the "Delete Nest" part from the #deleteButton button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  can wrap the added text in a `span` then it's possible to remove the added text by locating it as `next` element relatively to `i` element:

```js
$('#deleteButton').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).find('i').after('<span>Delete Nest</span>');
}).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).find('i').next().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the HTML of the button:

<button id="deleteButton" type="submit" name="_method" value="DELETE" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger muted muted-hover"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: Just saw this @antonku, seems to be the best out of the solutions I got :) Thank you!

Comment: @LouisD. Thank you for choosing my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```js
$('#deleteButton').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  //$(this).find('i').html(' Delete Nest');
  $(this).find('i').after('<span class="btnText">Delete Nest</span>');
  //$(this).find('i').after(' <div>Delete Nest</div>');
}).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  //$(this).find('i').html('');

  console.log($(this).find('i').after());

  $(this).find('.btnText').remove();
  //$(this).find('i').childNodes[1].textContent;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the HTML of the button:

<button id="deleteButton" type="submit" name="_method" value="DELETE" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger muted muted-hover"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: So I suppose there is no other way of removing it without a tag? Thank you for your solution though!

Comment: @LouisD. No you can remove without tag/element also check my answer.

Comment: @LouisD You can remove it without tag, but you will have to set button text to<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> each time.